# Set image height and width according to quantity of image in single div

Tags: jquery

I want to make image width 100% if div contain only one image but if more then one image then image is set according to item.

Ex. 1 image then width 100% and height 100%, 2 image then width 50% and height 50%,  3 image then width 33.333% and height 33.333%.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM82W.jpg)

Comment: For a simple and elegant approach you can use Bootstrap

Comment: Please solve this issue as soon as possible

Comment: Thanx lonut but how to use bcz we can give only bootstrap classes

Answer (score 0):

Try to pull out some images the others are going to take the place

```css
.container{display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; flex-direction: row;}
img{display: block; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: you dont get my point ,,, if only one image then its not fit to 100%

Comment: i try this thanks  its working. Good job. little more help i need only 4 image in one row how to break line

Comment: change the css to `.container{display: flex; justify-content: flex-start; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;}
img{display: block; max-width:25%; width:100%; object-fit: fill;}`